# Flutter : the code execution cannot proceed because flutter_windows.dll was not found. Reinstalling the program may fix this problem

Tags: flutter

Hello I am trying to create desktop app from flutter and I genrate exe file and .dll file also. When I install in my PC its perfectly work but when I share to other and they trying to install then its fire error **"flutter exe file error the code execution cannot proceed because flutter_windows.dll was not found. Reinstalling the program may fix this problem"**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

That `flutter_windows.dll` is one of the DLLs that must be included in the folder along with your EXE file. On your computer is probably already registered in Windows, so it won't be required: on other computers, you have to include it to be sure it will be available to your app.

See here: [link](https://docs.flutter.dev/platform-integration/windows/building#building-your-own-zip-file-for-windows)